# What does a: and r: in SOAP XML mean?

Tags: xml, wcf, soap

I am getting following XML SOAP response from my WCF request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <LoginUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <LoginUserResult 
        <a:NameFirst i:nil="true" />
        <a:NameLast i:nil="true" />
        <a:Response>
          <a:Code>1</a:Code>
          <a:Message>Invalid Password</a:Message>
        </a:Response>
      </LoginUserResult>
    </LoginUserResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

what do s:, a:, and r: (not shown here) mean? Are they required?
Are the response elements always ordered alphabetically?

Thanks

Comment: Those are **XML namespaces** (their prefixes, anyway). But that XML you're showing is not showing where the XML namespaces (and their prefixes) are defined.....

Comment: I have not defined the namespaces anywhere, they are created by default by WCF

Comment: No, the above XML is invalid _because_ it does not declare the `a` namespace.

Comment: It is also invalid because LoginUserResult does not have a closing >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s: namespace prefix is the namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ as defined in the Envelope root.

a: namespace prefix could be refering to custom namespace that should defined somewhere in the document, I've added it at the LoginUserResult, but it could be above that point as well.

The i: namespace prefix probably refers to the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance  I've also added that.

As you haven't shown r: we can't comment on that.

Are they required? If all the nodes are part of the default namespace, No, otherwise Yes (but they need to be defined).

Are the response elements always ordered alphabetically?  No.

P.S. you might want to get rid of the http://tempuri.org/ namespace as well.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <LoginUserResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <LoginUserResult xmlns:a="somenamespace" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:NameFirst i:nil="true" />
        <a:NameLast i:nil="true" />
        <a:Response>
          <a:Code>1</a:Code>
          <a:Message>Invalid Password</a:Message>
        </a:Response>
      </LoginUserResult>
    </LoginUserResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```